# db2 casting double to varchar without losing zeros

Tags: sql, db2

I have to check for wrong values using regexp_like expression. As far as I am concern I can do this only on strings and my data is saved in database as double.

I tried to cast it

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CAST(DECFLOAT(column) as VARCHAR(25)), '(\d{6}\.?\d{2})|(\d{7}\.?\d)')
```

Unfortunately values like 1234567.0 are converted into 1234567 and as a result this query is returning it as a mistake.

The other solution like

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CAST(CAST(column AS DECIMAL(8,1)) AS VARCHAR(25)), '(\d{6}\.?\d{2})|(\d{7}\.?\d)')
```

leads to a problem where values like `134567.89` are converted to `1234567.8` and are not returned by the query as an incorrect value.

Is there a way to cast it to `varchar` without giving it a range?

Comment: If you are checking for wrong values of a DOUBLE column, you should use mathematical comparisons instead of string comparisons. Converting to strings may be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

For 1st Query, Don't Convert column to **DECFLOAT**.

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CAST(CAST(column as DECIMAL(8,2)) as VARCHAR(25)), '(\d{6}\.?\d{2})|(\d{7}\.?\d)')
```

For 2nd Query, Increase the fraction part of the **DECIMAL(8,1)** to **DECIMAL(8,2)** to get the desired Result.

```
SELECT column
FROM tabel
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CAST(CAST(column AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS VARCHAR(25)), '(\d{6}\.?\d{2})|(\d{7}\.?\d)')
```

Comment: When I'm casting DOUBLE to VARCHAR i end up with scientific notation -  double(12345.6) into varchar(1.23456E4)

Comment: Cast Your Double Variable to Decimal and then cast it to **VARCHAR**